# NodeJs/ExcelJS: out of memory. Из-за чего происходит утечка памяти?

Tags: javascript, node.js

После пяти минут работы скрипт останавливается и выводит ошибку "out of memory". Вижу, что очень быстро прибавляется потребление оперативной памяти. Как это можно оптимизировать? Что в моем коде не так?

```js
 async getAll() {
        db.loadDatabase();
        db.ensureIndex({fieldName: 'id'});
        var categories = require("./categories");
        await workbook.xlsx.readFile("xlsx/template_all.xlsx");
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Лист1"); 
        for (var id in categories) {
            var mainCategoryName = categories[id].name;                            //имя главной категории
            var filename = mainCategoryName + "_" + new Date().format("dd-MM-Y") + ".xlsx";
            var row = 2;
            var numProducts = 0;
            for (var subc in categories[id].data.categories) {
                var subCategoryId = categories[id].data.categories[subc].id;                 //ID подкатегории
                var subCategoryName = categories[id].data.categories[subc].title;        //имя подкатегории
                for (var subc2 in categories[id].data.categories[subc].categories) {
                    var subCategory2Id = categories[id].data.categories[subc].categories[subc2].id;         //ID 2 подкатегории
                    var subCategory2Name = categories[id].data.categories[subc].categories[subc2].title;         //название 2 подкатегории
                    var subCategory2Url = categories[id].data.categories[subc].categories[subc2].url;       //ссылка на вторую категорию
                    var numPages = await this.getNumPages(subCategory2Url);
                    this.log(mainCategoryName + ">" + subCategoryName + ">" + subCategory2Name);
                    for (var page = 1; page <= numPages[0]; page++) {
                        var params = {"url": subCategory2Url + "?layout_container=categorySearchMegapagination&page=" + page};
                        var res = await this.req("https://www.ozon.ru/api/composer-api.bx/page/json/v1", params);
                        var keys = Object.keys(res.body.catalog.searchResultsV2);
                        var products = res.body.catalog.searchResultsV2[keys[keys.length - 1]].items;
                        for (var product in products) {
                            try {
                                var components = products[product].templateState[1].components;
                                var rating = this.getRating(components) || 0;
                                var maxItems = this.getMaxItems(components) || 0;
                                var seller = this.getSeller(components) || 0;
                            } catch (e) {
                                var rating = 0;
                                var maxItems = 0;
                                var seller = "";
                                fs.appendFileSync("errors.log", e + "\n\n" + JSON.stringify(products[product]) + "\n\n" + JSON.stringify(res.body) + "\n\n\n\n");
                            }
                                var periods = {"day": "J", "week": "K", "month": "L"};
                                worksheet.getCell("A" + row).value = products[product].cellTrackingInfo.id;
                                worksheet.getCell("B" + row).value = mainCategoryName;
                                worksheet.getCell("C" + row).value = subCategoryName;
                                worksheet.getCell("D" + row).value = subCategory2Name;
                                worksheet.getCell("E" + row).value = products[product].cellTrackingInfo.title;
                                worksheet.getCell("F" + row).value = products[product].cellTrackingInfo.finalPrice;
                                worksheet.getCell("G" + row).value = maxItems;
                                worksheet.getCell("H" + row).value = rating;
                                worksheet.getCell("I" + row).value = seller;
                                for (var period in periods) {
                                    worksheet.getCell(periods[period] + row).value = await this.getStat(products[product].cellTrackingInfo.id, period, maxItems);
                                }
                                await this.setMaxItems(products[product].cellTrackingInfo.id, maxItems);
                                this.log("#" + numProducts + " (" + page + ") " + products[product].cellTrackingInfo.title + " (" + products[product].cellTrackingInfo.id + ")");
                                row++;
                                numProducts++;
                               // global.gc();
                            //    console.log((process.memoryUsage().heapUsed/1024) / 1024);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            await workbook.xlsx.writeFile("xlsx/all/" + filename);
        }
    }
```

Comment: может данных очень много?

Comment: Ну да, строк много.

Comment: наверное есть способ поточной обработки и записи в файл

Comment: Есть, но я не понимаю, как им пользоваться)

Comment: я тут не подскажу, не пользовался этим в node...

Comment: readableStream, writeableStream, вот это все. https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream