# NodeJS/ExcelJS. Как выгрузить большое кол-во строк в excel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, request

Есть парсер, который получает 3000 строк в минуту. Необходимо записать все это в excel. Но возникла проблема: после пяти минут скрипт падает и выдает ошибку "out of memory". Использование памяти очень быстро растет. Знаю, что можно как-то делать запись потоками в excel, но у меня не получается. Я новичок в этом деле. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Скрипт можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074323/nodejs-exceljs-out-of-memory-%D0%98%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)

Comment: Вы по ходу выполнения скрипта просто докидываете и докидываете "строки" в память?

Comment: Ну они в цикле как бы докидываются, да. Но сама запись в файл происходит уже в конце цикла.

Comment: Ну вот она тут и течет. Ещё поди и памяти на процесс ноды по дефолту выделено?

Comment: Выделил 2 гига. Ну а как там по-другому сделать? Отдельным циклом?

Comment: Стримами и чистить уже записанное

Comment: Можно более подробно? Мне эти стримы даются очень сложно, не понимаю, как они работают